Change of Itinerary: Adding a Business Meeting top up
So when I applied, I stated single Schengen country as my only destination for tourism purpose and visa was granted.
Now, I wanted to modify my itinerary to also add a small extension to another Schengen country for business meeting though original country still remains my main destination as in max days spend there for tourism purpose.
My port of entry and exit will also be from the original Schengen country.
Am I allowed to do this?
I asked the embassy, they asked for my visa and intended dates. Their reply was bit scary:

As your travel plans have changed post receiving the visa, the Embassy
cannot provide you with any assurance that you shall be allowed to
board/enter Schengen. This is the decision taken by the concerned
immigration/border police.


You've already asked the embassy, nobody here knows more than those guys. My personal recommendation would be to go for your original trip, and if after you're in Europe then if a business trip comes up, you'd be free to undertake that as well.

If this is your first ever Schengen visa, personally I’d stick to the itinerary I submitted.

@Traveller this is my sixth but first on this visa issue. Also, I have active US, Canada, UK, Australia visas. Idk why this has to be so hard.
